# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^{\pi} \cos(ie^{ix}) ~dx$

Tags: calculus

[wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cint%5Climits_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%20%5Ccos%28ie%5E%7Bix%7D%29%20dx) says the definite integral evaluates to $\pi/2$. Any help/hints on how to approach these definite integrals that have no closed form for indefinite integral ?

Comment: The indefinite integral has a closed-form in term of [hyperbolic cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html). $$\int \cos\left(i \exp(ix)\right)dx = -i \operatorname{Chi}\left(\exp(ix)\right) + C.$$

Comment: Ohk..let me go through the definition of function thank you :)

Comment: From what I can tell, hyperbolic sine integral will also be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jordan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma#Application_of_Jordan.27s_lemma) comes to mind. You'll have to find residues first and check that lemma's conditions are satisfied. Use $\cos \left( {ix} \right) = \cosh x - i\sinh x$.